# Keyboard shortcut in finder to launch >share via>airdrop

Tags: applescript, automator, script, airdrop

I'm for a way to share a group of selected files I have selected in the finder window, via airdrop, with a simple keyboard shortcut. since you can use cmd+c to copy, I thought there had to be a way I could use comd+option+a to quickly make the selected files be shared via airdrop, but I am having no luck in finding a way to do so. I need to do this as some of the environments I'm in do not have great signal to power my hotspot, but I can compress photos for media purposes, and get them out instantly by airdropping to my phone, and sending via iMessage. I am decently fluent in automator, and have tried a few workarounds within the simple drag and drop. utilities, while searching google every which way from Sunday for help, and finally thought I would ask the question myself.

to be more clear when I press the keyboard shortcut, I would like for it to select this menu item.
[image]

which should bring up this screen.

[image]

Comment: I use keyboard maestro to configure my function keys.  It can do what you describe. You can use maestro for awhile free.

Comment: @historystamp How do you get _Keyboard Maestro_ to access the Airdrop contextual menu item?

Comment: I accomplish this on my system using _FastScripts_.

Comment: @CJK I had a feeling that for some of the things that I want to do that I would need to use scripts (which I've wanted to learn anyway).

Answer (score 8):

You can go to System prefrensces --> Keyboard --> Choose shortcuts from the menu above --> Choose "App shortcuts" from the side menu and click the + button. After that choose Finder and you will get a box with two text boxes.

Fill the first with exactly "AirDrop" (notice the A and D are capital) and fill the other box with the shortcut you wish the assign with this action and thats it. [image: As the linked picture shows.]

Comment: This is how I do it, also.  Worth noting that it's also possible to define this shortcut under _All Applications_ to make it available in any application for which the option to share via AirDrop is available via a main menu or a context menu.

Comment: Anyway to get this to work with Ventura?  Now there is a stupid "Share..." menu item instead.  And when you click it... only THEN will it pop up a window to select AirDrop from...

Answer (score 5):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

Here is a solution that may work for you.  You can customize your Finder toolbar and add the “Share” Icon to the toolbar.

[image]

Next create a new Automator Quick Service document and add a new run AppleScript command to the workflow.  Next, paste this following code into that new AppleScript command (overwriting the placeholder text)

```
tell application "Finder" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Finder"
        repeat until UI element "Share" of toolbar 1 of window 1 exists
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        click UI element "Share" of toolbar 1 of window 1
        repeat until menu item "AirDrop" of menu 1 of UI element ¬
            "Share" of toolbar 1 of window 1 exists
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        click menu item "AirDrop" of menu 1 of UI element ¬
            "Share" of toolbar 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

After you save and name your Automator Quick Action / Service document, you can assign it a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences.

[image]

Now with any file that you have selected in Finder, using your new keyboard shortcut will add that selected file to a new AirDrop pop-up window.

[image]

For reasons which I do not understand…  in the AppleScript code after it clicks the “Share” Icon in the Finder toolbar, for some reason, there is about a 4 second lag before it clicks the “AirDrop” menu item.  I've spent over an hour trying to figure out why  there is a delay between the two commands… but to no avail.   Maybe someone else can find a solution for that.  Otherwise I think my solution accomplishes what you need.

Comment: its locking up my system for a second, and then shows a spinning gear in the menu bar, with a progress bar that reads 0%, and does not go any further. but that does help me find out where the share button lives in AppleScript. I have had that share button on my finder windows since day 1, but maybe the issue is its in a different order than you? I am on the latest version of Mojave as well.

Comment: Try pasting the code into Script Editor.app after you have a selected file in the your Finder window and run the code in Script Editor.app.  Let's see what happens

Comment: No, I'm afraid your solution doesn't work in _High Sierra_, but I suspect this will be due to OS interface changes. The 4-second delay is not because of anything you've done wrongly: it's a well-known and -documented phenomenon going back some years, and there are no known solutions or reliable workarounds.